Screenshots not included in xcresult bundles after successful UITests in Xcode 16.1 on MacOS Sequoia
I am using Xcode 16.1 (16B40) on MacOS Sequoia 15.1.0 using a Macbook pro M1 Max
I am developing an app for iOS 17 and 18 using SwiftUI I created UITests to take the screenshots for the appStore on the simulator
The tests run well and all of them are succeded
The problem appears when I try to get the screenshot files from the xcresult files after the test. There is not any screenshot inside it.
I found a data folder and a Info.plist file. In the data folder there are a lot of files with this pattern data.03zD4C6IGFFthK14NwA8mNvcwFHT16g6Tl40Tl1YmBC1bNh6d0YIcnWKyUaQPDXoa8fYo6C3Xcv8xvMtE3_NEXA== and other files with this pattern refs.03zD4C6IGFFthK14NwA8mNvcwFHT16g6Tl40Tl1YmBC1bNh6d0YIcnWKyUaQPDXoa8fYo6C3Xcv8xvMtE3_NEXA==
Ok, I tryed to use fastlane to automatize the screenshots but the problem is still present. The xcresult files have not any png file.
I had no problems doing this action (getting screenshots from a xcresult file) in previous versions of MacOS and Xcode in my current machine.
I just updated my machine to MacOS Sequoia 15.1.1 and the problem is still present
Honestly I don't know how to fix this situation.
With Xcode 15 I had not any problem with that but I am not sure if Xcode 16.0 was runing without problems because I didn't need to use this functionality in those months
Here is my code for a UITest:
import XCTest

final class ScreenshotsUITests: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let device = "iPhone16"
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = true
        
    }
    
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {}
    
    @MainActor
    func testEnglishScreens() throws {
        let lang = "en"
        app.launchArguments.append("UITestMode")
        app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(en)"]
        app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLocale", "en_US"]
        app.launch()
        executeTestsForMenus(lang: lang, backLabel: "Back")
        executeTestForMatch(lang: lang)
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func testSpanishScreens() throws {
        let lang = "es"
        app.launchArguments.append("UITestMode")
        app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLanguages", "(es)"]
        app.launchArguments += ["-AppleLocale", "es_ES"]
        app.launch()
        executeTestsForMenus(lang: lang, backLabel: "Atrás")
        executeTestForMatch(lang: lang)
    }
    
    private func executeTestForMatch(lang: String) {
        let startButton = app.buttons["start-button"]
        startButton.tap()
        
        let key4 = app.buttons["key-4"]
        XCTAssertTrue(key4.waitForExistence(timeout: 30), "Key 4 in match screen is not found")
        key4.tap()
        let key2 = app.buttons["key-2"]
        XCTAssertTrue(key2.exists, "Key 2 in match screen is not found")
        key2.tap()
        makeScreenShot("playing", lang: lang)
        let closeButton = app.buttons["close-button"]
        XCTAssertTrue(closeButton.exists, "Close button in match screen is not found")
        closeButton.tap()
    }
    
    private func executeTestsForMenus(lang: String, backLabel: String) {
        let mainHeader = app.staticTexts["Math match"]
        XCTAssertTrue(mainHeader.exists, "Header in main screen is not found")
        makeScreenShot("mainMenu", lang: lang)
        
        let settingsButton = app.buttons["settings-button"]
        XCTAssertTrue(settingsButton.exists, "Settings button in main screen is not found")
        settingsButton.tap()
        makeScreenShot("Settings", lang: lang)
        let backButton = app.buttons[backLabel]
        XCTAssertTrue(backButton.exists, "Back button in match screen is not found")
        backButton.tap()
        
        let helpButton = app.buttons["help-button"]
        XCTAssertTrue(helpButton.exists, "Help button in main screen is not found")
        helpButton.tap()
        makeScreenShot("Help", lang: lang)
        backButton.tap()
        let scoreButton = app.buttons["score-button"]
        XCTAssertTrue(scoreButton.exists, "Scores button in main screen is not found")
        scoreButton.tap()
        makeScreenShot("Scores", lang: lang)
        backButton.tap()
        let playButton = app.buttons["play-button"]
        XCTAssertTrue(playButton.exists, "Play button in main screen is not found")
        playButton.tap()
        makeScreenShot("matchBuilder", lang: lang)
        let startButton = app.buttons["start-button"]
        XCTAssertTrue(startButton.exists, "Start button in match builder screen is not found")
    }
    
    private func makeScreenShot(_ name: String, lang: String) {
        takeScreenshot(app, named: "\(lang)-\(name)-\(device)")
    }
}

import XCTest

extension XCTestCase {
    func takeScreenshot(_ app: XCUIApplication, named name: String, fullScreen: Bool = false) {
        let screenshot: XCUIScreenshot
        if fullScreen {
            screenshot = app.windows.firstMatch.screenshot()
        } else {
            screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
        }
        let screenshotAttachment = XCTAttachment(
            uniformTypeIdentifier: "public.png",
            name: "screenshot-\(name).png",
            payload: screenshot.pngRepresentation,
            userInfo: nil)
        screenshotAttachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
        add(screenshotAttachment)
    }
}

and here is the content of my testplan file:
{
  "configurations" : [
    {
      "id" : "35BC7C0B-9A5A-4027-9F30-36958C4C1AAF",
      "name" : "Test Scheme Action",
      "options" : {
        "preferredScreenCaptureFormat" : "screenshot",
        "testExecutionOrdering" : "random",
        "uiTestingScreenshotsLifetime" : "keepAlways",
        "userAttachmentLifetime" : "keepAlways"
      }
    }
  ],
  "defaultOptions" : {
    "targetForVariableExpansion" : {
      "containerPath" : "container:myAppProject.xcodeproj",
      "identifier" : "B27D1B022CA00314001A259B",
      "name" : "MyAppProject"
    }
  },
  "testTargets" : [
    {
      "parallelizable" : true,
      "target" : {
        "containerPath" : "container:MyAppProject.xcodeproj",
        "identifier" : "B27D1B122CA00315001A259B",
        "name" : "MyAppProjectTests"
      }
    },
    {
      "parallelizable" : true,
      "target" : {
        "containerPath" : "container:MyAppProject.xcodeproj",
        "identifier" : "B27D1B1C2CA00315001A259B",
        "name" : "MyAppProjectUITests"
      }
    }
  ],
  "version" : 1
}

I made tests with old projects in my machine and those projects have the same problem with screenshot files in the xcresult bundles
I could check the reports in Xcode using a shared eye (I am blind) and in the test reports the screenshots are available and I can export them but they are not present in the xcresult bundles and I cannot use automatic tools to create my screenshots for the AppStore :-(
I don't know if the problem is in my machine, my Xcode, MacOS or other ting. I don't know how to fix this problem
Please, can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance
